Is Permanent App Kiosk Mode possible in Android/React-Native?
My client wants me to make the app permanently in kiosk mode so that it cannot be exited unless the device is rebooted. I've tried react-native npm packages that implement a kiosk mode but they simply do the app pinning feature which can easily be bypassed by pressing the home and power button at the same time.
I want to know if such is a permanent locking feature is even possible? If not can someone kindly confirm so I may let my client know. If there are any solutions please do share.
I tried the react-native-kiosk and react-native-kiosk-mode and react-native-lock-task packages they all did the same thing. App pinning which could be bypassed.

See my related discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/78902707/78907092
